# Continuation frame cannot follow current opcode

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm using [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) in a Node websocket server.

In production, I frequently get this error:

```
Error: continuation frame cannot follow current opcode
```

What is causing this?

How should go about debugging and replicating this error in a development environment?

EDIT:

Doesn't seem to be specific to a browser, I've captured these errors in connections from Chrome, Firefox and IE10 and from different operating systems.

EDIT 2:

Error is thrown [here](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/0dce161f838e73581d96bd6f0ef6c78a675e6c20/lib/Receiver.js#L198). Apparently after receiving a frame with opcode 0 after a frame with a code != 1 && != 2.

EDIT 3:

[RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2), section 5.2, shows what the opcodes mean and the frame's anatomy.

Answer (score 2):

You might run [Autobahn Testsuite](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/) (in fuzzing client mode) against your server. This will give you a detailed report like [this](http://autobahn.ws/testsuite/reports/servers/index.html) (including wirelogs) of issues encountered.

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Answer (score 1):

For a continuation frame to work the frame before it needs to be a continuation frame or an initial frame of 1/text or 2/binary. So a frame that is not a continuation, text or binary frame is being sent. Or a new text or binary frame is being sent before it should.

To debug you need to analyze the code on the client side and check the frames on the sever side to figure out why it's sending frames out of order.

Comment: Per the spec, a continuation (opcode 0) frame can follow any fin==false data frame (opcodes 0, 1, or 2), or ping (opcode 9), or pong (opcode 10).  Note that ping/pong can be in the middle of a set of frames, having no impact on the overall message that those frames make up.

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this error, and it was caused by this code in my server.js:

```
wss.on('connection', function (client, request) {
    wsg = client;
    client._socket.setEncoding('utf8'); // <== oops, don't do this
    // ...
}
```